# Integrating Laplacian

Tags: calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral

I came across the following result in the Griffith's textbook,
$$\int \frac{d^2\psi}{dr^2}dr=\Delta \psi',$$ where $\psi(r)=rR(r)$ is a solution to the radial Schrödinger equation
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dr^2}+\left(V(r)+\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}\right)\psi=E\psi.$$
However, mathematically, I don't see how this is possible, why would integral of the Laplacian of the function equal the Laplacian of the derivative?

Comment: I don't know where this appears in the text (or what edition, or even which book by Griffith). But here, $\Delta$ almost certainly means "change" in instead of Laplacian. i.e. $\int_a^b \psi'' dr = \psi'(b) - \psi'(a)$.